# How to loop a section of code in nodejs for a set amount of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, time

I'm trying to make a game, and it needs to keep looping for X seconds of time, preferably something that I can change.

```js
var startTime = Date.now();
while ((Date.now() - startTime) < guessTheWordDuration) {
  //game code
  
 }
```

I have tried this but it does not seem to work, setting it to one number just seems to loop it infinitely.

Any help is appreciated!

This is in nodejs v8

Comment: You generally don't want to do this because it will block the thread. There is usually a better way, but it's hard to suggest one because we don't know what `guessTheWordDuration` does. Can you add some more details?

Comment: What is this game supposed to do? What do the clients do and how shozld the server react?

Comment: node.js is event driven.  You respond to events.  You don't loop like this.  So, you would either be responding to input events or set a timer and respond to a timer event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How often do you need the while loop to tick?  I would maybe do something like this.

```
function gameLoop () {
  // do stuff
  setTimeout(() => {
    gameLoop();
  }, 100); // makes the thread non blocking for 100 ms
}

gameLoop();
```

Then you just have to create a variable for your timeout and cancel it if you'd like to stop the loop.